# Number of edges in a digraph?

Tags: graph-theory

I know this might be similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058406/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-edges-in-a-directed-graph-with-n-nodes), but I would like to know what the maximum number of edges in a digraph would be if parallel edges (aka multi-edges) are *not* allowed. I know that the maximum number of edges, given `V` vertices, would be $$V * (V - 1).$$

Comment: You already gave the answer yourself... The maximum of $V(V-1)$ is true *only* under the assumption that there are no parallel edges. If you mean that it is also not allowed to have edges a->b and b->a at the same time, the answer is $V(V-1)/2 = \binom{V}{2}$.

Comment: Oh wow. I'm dumb. Thanks

Comment: This should be turned into an answer so that the question appears as answered for the community.

Comment: @ViniciusdosSantos I just did. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @user133281:

> The maximum of $V(V−1)$ is true *only* under the assumption that there are no parallel edges. If you mean that it is also not allowed to have edges $a \rightarrow b$ and $b \rightarrow a$ at the same time, the answer is
>
> $$\frac {V(V-1)}{2} = \binom {V}{2} $$